# nodejs, right catching of value from backend in JS frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug, frontend

i have such object in my node.js backend:

```
dataOne = [
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 597
    },
    {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 298
    },
    {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 325
    }]
```

and i`m using this :

```
res.render('index', {data: dataOne})
```

Now, in my JADE file I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        displayGraphExampleOne("#graph1", 400/4, 100/4, "basis", #{data});
    });
```

but #{data} is returning like : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

how I can parse my #{data} to javaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the data is already parsed. Try serialize it then render template.

```
displayGraphExampleOne("#graph1", 400/4, 100/4, "basis", !{JSON.stringify(data)} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I wouldn't really recommend passing your data down like that, you could try using `JSON.parse()`.

Something like

```
displayGraphExampleOne("#graph1", 400/4, 100/4, "basis", JSON.parse(#{data}));
```

And then you'd have to pass it down as `JSON.stringify(dataOne)`;

Comment: i`m getting JSON.parse([object Object],[object Object],[object Object])

Comment: Did you call `toString()` on the data server side?

Comment: Oh, you'd have to call `toString()` on each of the nested objects as well. Try `JSON.stringify(dataOne)`